# automated submit query in html?

Tags: javascript, php, html, automation, form-submit

For this piece of code I found on a site, I altered it and when it runs in my browser and then I wish to submit again for an automation process of data manipulation, I can not seem to figure out how to actually ensure the element is "submitted" or posted.

```
<input id="element_1" name="element_1" class="element text large" type="text" maxlength="400" style="padding-left:5px" value="my_altered_value">
```

What would I have to add to this code so that it submits this element and goes to the next link which the site does itself after pasting "my_altered_value" and  then proceeds to the next web-page?

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: I attempted to clean up your explanation a little to make it more clear. You need to show a bit more code. For example, you say the site proceeds to the next page. Is that code you wrote? Is there back end code this value is being submitted to? You haven't given enough information for people to help you. Try editing the question and adding more code you have written and explaining a little more what you are attempting to do and what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible (but maybe long way) is to use Javascript's onmouseleave on every input.
e.g.
    if(input1!="" && input2!=""){window.open("...");}

Hope it helps!